# Title bar appeared again after coming back in my application

Tags: android

In my application, I have applied following theme in my manifest file:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and it is working fine.
But when I call someone from my app as per application requirement, and come back again in my application after call end, title bar appears in app again. I am not getting that what is the problem. Please help me out.

I don't want a title bar in my application at all.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/K0gGYD5HuTg):

Sounds like the following will fix it:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: No this won't worked for me. actually in my case when i make call from my app, i just come out from app and it shows native call screen.and after call end i again come back in app but at that point title bar appears.

Comment: actually its not an app its a launcher and when i select my custom launcher then i want to disappear title bar. Its working fine when i am launching my launcher first time but when i close my launcher and start the native launcher and again come back in my launcher then title bar appears again on that page